# Passing data from main to renderer (electron-js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am fiddeling around with electron. In my app I have a Javascript object containing all of the settings for my app. This object has a key called "renderer" that I would like to pass to the rendered windows to keep all the settings in one convenient place.

I have been looking around the documentation and the best way I have found is the following (aside from passing variables through the process.argv via BrowserWindow's additionalarguments).

In main.js:

```
ipcMain.handle('getSettings', () => {
        return settings.renderer
    })
```

preload.js

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('bridge', {
    getSettings: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('getSettings')
})
```

renderer.js

```
    function getSettings() {
        settings = window.bridge.getSettings().then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
    }

    getSettings()
```

**Is there a more convienent way to accomplish this and at that, is this possible to accomplish in a synchronous manner?**

Comment: No to both, afaik, but there's this: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-3-main-to-renderer

Comment: `invoke` and `handle` is an asynchronous way to communicate between the render -> main -> render. [Pattern2: render to main (two-way)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-2-renderer-to-main-two-way). Alternatively, you can send a message from render to main ([Pattern 1: Render to main (one-way)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-1-renderer-to-main-one-way)) and when ready (in your own time, synchronously), main to render [Pattern 3: Main to render](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-3-main-to-renderer)

Answer (score 12):

Once your window has been created and loaded you can immediately send your settings object to the render process via
IPC.

- Use [contents.send(channel, ...arg)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args)
  to send data to the render process.
- Use [ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener)
  within your `preload.js` script to receive data from the main process.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

// Settings object
let settings = {
    'renderer': {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2'
    }
}

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.webContents.send('sendSettings', settings.renderer); })
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'bridge', {
        // From main to render
        sendSettings: (message) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('sendSettings', message);
        }
    }
);
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>See Developer Tools -> Console</p>
    </body>

    <script>
        window.bridge.sendSettings((event, settings) => {
            console.log(settings);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Important note to highlight: ONLY preload can receive ipcRenderer events!

Comment: It's confusing that both preload and main.js are the main process. Wouldhave been better if the preload was called middle process.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is "Passing data from main to renderer"; NOT the other way around. While ipcMain is well documented for renderer to main (where the renderer is the origin of inquiry); but the other way around, if you simply want to send data ***originating from main*** to the render process you can use `webContents.executeJavaScript` to send data to the render process' window. I.e. from within main.js, you create the BrowserWindow:

```
const BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 640, height: 480 });
win.webContents.loadFile('index.html');
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  win.webContents.executeJavaScript("console.log('hello from main');");
});
```

The proceeding creates a new window, loads the file index.html, and then main proceeds to send data via `executeJavaScript`. No ipcMain nor preload.js needed. This is one-way and addresses the user's initial inquiry.

Comment: I think this is not the right way!!! It executes the JavaScript code on renderer. To send data right way is to use `webContets.send()` method as explained above by @midnight-coding.