# signal from Main to Renderer not reaching contextBridge?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

When the app is launched, I am trying to send some data from `main.js` to `renderer.js` so that `renderer.js` can begin rendering some elements. I have no idea what is going wrong, but it seems communication breaks down at `preload.js`. I have checked Electron's documentation and my code looks fine. I have no problem communicating from `renderer.js` to `main.js` to `renderer.js`, but communicating from `main.js` to `renderer.js` does not want to work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

As per @elichen's instruction, I tested `ipcRenderer.on('data:dataList',()=>console.log('called'))` at the top of `preload.js` and this is logging... What the heck is going on here?

```
// main.js

async function readJSON(filePath) {
  try {
    const data = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8')
    return JSON.parse(data)
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'ENOENT') return []
    else throw error
  }
}

async function loadData() {
  try {
    const
      configFilePath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'List of Data Points.json'),
      dataList = await readJSON(configFilePath)
    if (dataList.length) {
      console.log(dataList.length) //## THIS LOGS CORRECTLY ##//
      mainWindow.webContents.send('data:dataList', dataList)
      console.log('Sent data from main.js') //## THIS LOGS TO MAIN.JS CONSOLE ##//
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading configuration file:', error)
  }
}

app.whenReady().then(()=>{
  createWindow()
  loadData()
  ...
```

```
// preload.js

ipcRenderer.on('data:dataList',()=>console.log('called')) //## THIS LOGS ##//

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI',
  {
    onDataListReady: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('data:dataList', (_event, value) => {
      console.log('Why does this not work?') //## THIS DOES NOT LOG ##//
      return callback(value)
    }),
    ...
```

```
// renderer.js

window.myAPI.onDataListReady((value) => {
  console.log(value) //## THIS DOES NOT LOG TO BROWSER CONSOLE ##//
  try {
    dataList.forEach(it=>console.log(it))
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in onDataListReady:', error)
  }
})
```

Comment: Function exposed from preload is named `onDataListReady`, on renderer you call `onFontListReady`.

Comment: @Arkellys its actually `onFontListReady` everywhere, but i changed it to `onDataListReady` to post it publicly. thats not the issue. the `console.log` in `preload.js` isnt even being logged, so the script doesnt seem to progress to even there

Comment: maybe its because you called `loadData` before `window.myAPI.onDataListReady` actually called. so when `loadData` called the preload not listing to the `data:dataList`. try to listing to `data:dataList` immediatly and not inside the function which call later and check if it called

Comment: @elichen im not even sure the signal is progressing to `preload.js` as the `console.log` in `(_event, value){}` is not being logged. aside from that, this separation/isolation (i.e. not returning it directly), i believe, is done for security purposes according to the documentation. thx for your response nonetheless

Comment: im not talking about separation/isolation that ok. but when the when you call loadData from main to preload. the onDataListReady which actually create the listner for the `data:dataList` not yet created. try to write at the top of preload file the line `ipcRenderer.on('data:dataList',()=>console.log('called'))` and check if its called. if so then the reason is as above

Comment: @elichen ohhh, i see what youre saying. just tested it and that is not even logging for some reason -.-a what the heck is going on with this

Comment: try to move the `loadData` to `XX.webContents.on("did-finish-load",()=>loadData())` its seems like loadData called some how before the listering created

Comment: @elichen whoops. it actually did log. i forgot to change the namespace back from `dataList` to what im actually using in the code... ive been awake for far too long cuz i cant sleep lol

Comment: @elichen that worked! submit it below and ill mark it as the answer. tysm <333

Comment: @elichen the whole reason why i wanted to send the data from main to renderer (instead of requesting the data from renderer) was to speed up the process of providing the data to renderer. but i guess it is not possible to speed it up like that :(

Comment: its possible but not in the way you tried to do that :-)

Comment: @elichen but it is not possible to "preload" it or, in other words, send the data before the `dom-ready` event, which i guess makes sense. cant have my cake and eat it too haha

Comment: An alternative and possibly simpler solution could be to send your `data` on window creation. IE: Hide window with `show: false`, load window with `loadFile()`, send data with `mywin.webContents.send()` and then finally show window with `show()`. See the `createWindow()` function within `main.js` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73133878/2627338 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason `ipcRenderer.on('data:dataList',...` not called is because the order of things

1. `createWindow()` at this step the preload is loading but the listener for `data:dataList` not yet created. (its created by calling `onDataListReady` which calls later)
2. `loadData()` at this step the main send to preload the event but no one listening to that event
3. the render called `onDataListReady` which only now create the listener.

the fix to that problem is normally subject to implementation of the app. a small fix can be by calling `loadData` after all dom and js loaded for example using `did-finish-load` event like below

```
createWindow(){
...
mywin.webContents.on('did-finish-load',()=>loadData())
...
}
```